# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.utils._typedefs'

Tags: scikit-learn, pyinstaller

When I try to execute the exe file made my pyinstaller I got the error message
No module named 'sklearn.utils._typedefs'.  I use `from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier` in my python code.

I did use the --hidden-import and solve the problem before but when I try use the different version's python it didn't works

The command I use is
`pyinstaller --hidden-import="sklearn.utils._cython_blas" --hidden-import="sklearn.neighbors.typedefs" --hidden-import="sklearn.neighbors.quad_tree" --hidden-import="sklearn.tree._utils" -F myprgname.py`

The old setting works

Python 3.6.8
`pyinstaller==4.6`
`pyinstaller-hooks-contrib==2021.3`
`python-dateutil==2.8.2`
`pytz==2021.3`
`scikit-learn==0.24.2`

The new setting (got error message above)

Python 3.7.8
`pyinstaller==5.0.1`
`pyinstaller-hooks-contrib==2022.4`
`python-dateutil==2.8.2`
`pytz==2022.1`
`scikit-learn==1.0.2`

any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue today, I resolved it by adding news hidden imports :

```
--hidden-import="sklearn.utils._typedefs"
```

This one may be sufficient for your issue, but for me, I had to add also :

```
--hidden-import="sklearn.neighbors._partition_nodes"
```

Here is the full command that I used :

```
pyinstaller --hidden-import="sklearn.utils._cython_blas" --hidden-import="sklearn.neighbors.typedefs" --hidden-import="sklearn.neighbors.quad_tree" --hidden-import="sklearn.tree._utils" --hidden-import="sklearn.neighbors._typedefs" --hidden-import="sklearn.utils._typedefs" --hidden-import="sklearn.neighbors._partition_nodes" --onefile MyPythonScript.pyw
```

My environment :

```
Python 3.9.12
Pyinstaller 5.0.1
pyinstaller-hooks-contrib==2022.4
python-dateutil==2.8.2
scikit-learn==1.0.2
pytz == none
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and I could't solve it adding the --hidden-import flag.

I had scikit-learn==1.0.2 and pyinstaller==4.10

Downgrading it to scikit-learn==1.0.1 solved the problem.

```
pip install -U scikit-learn==1.0.1
```

I guess it is a compatibility problem.

Answer (score 1):

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.utils'.

This is the problem you have when converting from python to an executable.

Knowing that I am using python 3.8, I had the same issue today. I resolved it by adding new hidden imports:

```
--hidden-import="sklearn.utils._typedef"
```

Didn't accept it at the command prompt  CMD

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Did this solve the issue, or not? The beginning seems to suggest it did. The last sentence seems to suggest it didn't. Also, shouldn't it be `_typedefs`, as per the previous answer?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, solved it by installing `pyinstaller-hooks-contrib==2023.5`